Question about modular group (Modular theory in operator algebras, section 2.14)
Consider the following fragment from Stratila's book "Modular theory in operator algebras", section 2.14, p20:

I'm trying to understand the claim $(3)$ (see the red box). The main strategy is clear:
There exist $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\ge 0$ and a $\sigma$-weakly continuous function
$F: \{\beta: -\epsilon_1 \le \Re\beta \le \epsilon_2\}\to \mathscr{M}$ analytic on the interior of the domain, such that $-\epsilon_1 \le \Re \alpha \le \epsilon_2$ and such that $F(it) = \sigma_t^\varphi(a)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
Futher, write $\alpha= s_0+it_0$ with $s_0,t_0\in \mathbb{R}$. We may assume $s_0\ne 0$, otherwise the claim $(3)$ is trivial. WLOG, $s_0 > 0$. Then $\xi \in D(\Delta_\varphi^\alpha)= D(\Delta_\varphi^{s_0})$ and there exists a norm-continuous bounded function
$$G: \{\beta: 0 \le \Re \beta \le s_0\}\to \mathcal{H}_\varphi$$
analytic on its interior and such that $G(it) = \Delta_\varphi^{it}\xi$.
The strategy should then be to show that
$$H(\beta):= \pi_\varphi(F(\beta))G(\beta)$$
is the desired analytic bounded continuous function such that
$$H(it) = \Delta_\varphi^{it}\pi_\varphi(a)\xi, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
However, two things are not clear to me:
(1) Why is $H$ bounded? I can see this is true if $F$ is bounded. Maybe this is a consequence of the analyticity of $F$ or something like that?
(2) Why is $H$ norm-continuous, i.e. if $\beta_n \to \beta$, why do we have
$$\|\pi_\varphi(F(\beta_n))G(\beta_n)-\pi_\varphi(F(\beta))G(\beta)\| \to 0.$$
Thanks in advance for your help/comments!

I fully agree that there is a lot of confusion in the literature on the precise definition of these analytic continuations $\sigma^\varphi_\alpha$. This is discussed with great care and neatly clarified in Section 2 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.03661 by Matthew Daws. As a result in the context that you are considering, $F$ is automatically bounded in operator norm (see Remark 2.4 in that paper) and also automatically continuous if we equip $\mathcal{M}$ with the strong$^*$-topology rather than the weak topology (see Theorem 2.16 in that paper). From here, you immediately get positive answers to (1) and (2).

Thanks for pointing out this nice reference. That indeed clears everything up!
